# Multiple WARs vs single WAR application

Tags: spring, gwt, jpa, deployment

We are about to create our new server and are pondering the question:

Should we use a single WAR (web application) or break down our application into multiple modules each one is a single WAR file?

Obviously the multiple wars option makes i easier to deploy single features without taking down the application.

What are exactly the pros cons of each methodology?

Our project is is a backoffice admin application, we are using spring \ jpa \ mongodb and GWT for our client side.

Comment: what is supposed you are going to have in each .war? are you thinking on communicate those wars, I mean server -> server ?

Comment: yeah, i'm using activemq as a bus for all the app modules

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it by you should check if you will have issues on copying session data from one web app to the other or if you can reuse the same one (since you're on the same server domain url)

I don't see a real reason to do that unless you have two different applications (or at least actors: ex: admin application and user app). This is maybe the case you're describing: having multiple separately updatable parts of the app. You should also check if it will not be confusing in the future to know which version works with wich one (at lease use a packaging system like Maven or Gradle where you will strictly declare compatibilities of each war)

Unless this presents a sense, I would rather recommand splitting your app into multiple jars and one war: the unit tests are easier to apply on jars than on wars.

I'm convinced that taking down the app is not as big trouble as taking the risk of deploying uncompatible versions... and fixing it for hours

I hope my opinion helped,
Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi